# c# algorithm to calculate the discount that is subtracted from the total amount onto each purchased item instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

At the moment I am giving a fixed discount to a purchase of multiple items on my webshop. 
so for instance the buyer might get a discount of 25$ of the total price of 100$ - so in the end he will pay 75$. 
The payment transaction card middleman now wants me to add the discount to each item that the buyer purchases. So if he buys the following
2 hats: 25$ each 
1 umbrella: 20$
1 t-shirt: 30$
then how do I subtract the correct discount that I normally subtract from the total price onto each item in the purchase instead?

It would be great if someone could help me write an algorithm for this in c#

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It isn't a forum to make your work.

Comment: Couldn't you just take 25% off the unit price of each item when the total is over $100.00?

Comment: but the 25% was just an example it could be anything.

Comment: At some point you must know how much you're discounting. Take that number, divide by the number of purchased items and apply the result to each item.

Comment: Small steps... I assume you know how to adjust the total. Now make the fixed adjustment off each subtotal. Then make the fixed adjustment a variable. Finally, lookup the the correct adjustment by product (or whatever is applies to your application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the current code you have? A C# example would look something like this:

`// Assuming 'items' is an Enumerable type containing the list of items in the order
var totalCost = 0;
for (var i in items) {
// Accumulates the cost of each item at a 25% discount
  totalCost += 0.75 * i.Cost;
}`